# Weeknum Functions return types Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery, week-number, m

With the limitations in the Weeknum standard function in Power Query, does anyone have any M-Code with which a function can be invoked to give different Weeknum return types (specifically, in Excel it's be Weeknum (date,14)).

I found this to give me ISO weeknums:

```
let
    Thursday  = Date.AddDays(DateParameter,3-Date.DayOfWeek(DateParameter,Day.Monday)),
    Jan1 = #date(Date.Year(Thursday),1,1),
    Days = Number.From(Thursday - Jan1),
    Result = Number.RoundDown(Days/7)+1
in
    Result
```

But I cannot get my around how to modify this to make the weeks start on a Thursday (I'm sure it'll be simple!)

Thanks in advance for your help - much appreciated.

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt253480.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function Date.WeekOfYear has an undocumented second argument in which you can provide the first day of the week, i.c. Date.WeekOfYear(date,Day.Thursday).

Note: if January 1 is a Wednesday, then January 2 is aleady week 2 (so not like ISO).

Comment: i now see it was actually your Youtube tutorial where I got the ISO week function - thanks for that too!!!

Comment: MarcelBeug - I bet you'd be able to answer this: I now need to create a Custom Column that has a TRUE/FALSE value based on whether the value in my 'WeekNumber' field on each row equals the MAX value in that entire field. Easy in Excel....Cheers